# Location of DW_FORM_strp values

Tags: elf, dwarf

I'm trying to understand where `DW_FORM_strp` attribute values are actually stored in an ELF file (can be found here: https://filebin.net/77bb8359o0ibqu67).

I've found sections `.debug_info`, `.debug_abbrev` and `.debug_str`. I've then parsed the compilation unit header in `.debug_info`, and found the abbreviation table entry for the compile unit and iterated over its abbreviations. The first abbreviation is `DW_AT_producer` with form `DW_FORM_strp`. What I'm wondering is how to find where this offset is located?

From the DWARF4 spec I read: `Each debugging information entry begins with a code that represents an entry in a separate abbreviations table. This code is followed directly by a series of attribute values.` My understanding of this is that if I go back to the compilation unit header, skip over its content, I should end up at the compilation unit. It starts with a ULEB128 (which I parse), after which the attribute values should come. However, in my ELF file those bytes are all 0. I've run `readelf -w` on the file, and I see the following:

```
Contents of the .debug_info section:

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
   Length:        0xf6 (32-bit)
   Version:       4
   Abbrev Offset: 0x0
   Pointer Size:  8
 <0><b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <c>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x62): GNU C11 7.5.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -O0 -fstack-protector-strong
    <10>   DW_AT_language    : 12   (ANSI C99)
    <11>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xd9): elf.c
    <15>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0xad): /home//struct_analyzer
    <19>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x0
    <21>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x39
    <29>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0
```

This tells me that the offset into the string table is `0x62`, and the name is at an offset `0xd9`. However, after parsing the `ULEB128` which is the first part of any DIE, the next 4 bytes (the first attribute's value) are `0x00 00 00 00`. This I don't understand?

**Edit** to *Employed Russian*:

Yes, I understand that the offset `0x62` points into the `.debug_str` section. However, what I'm wondering is where I find this `0x62` value?

Each DIE starts with a ULEB128 value (the abbreviation table entry code), and is followed by the attributes. The first attribute in the corresponding abbreviation table entry is a `DW_AT_producer` of form `DW_FORM_strp`. This means that the next 4 bytes in the DIE are supposed to be the offset into `.debug_str`. However, the next 4 bytes are `0x00 00 00 00`, and not `0x62 00 00 00` which is the value I'm looking. `0x62` is residing at offset `0x5c8` into the ELF file, whereas the DIE's attributes start at offset `0x85` as far as I can tell (see attached image for a hexdump (little endian) - highlighted byte is the ULEB128, and the following bytes are what I expect to be the offset into `.debug_str`).
[image]

**Edit 2**

I've been able to determine that the actual attribute values of form `DW_FORM_strp` are located in the `.rela.debug_info` section in the ELF file, so I'll have to read more about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific ELF file posted for this question also has a `rela.debug_info` section, which contains relocation entries for the `.debug_info` section. From the ELF spec:

```
 .relaNAME
              This section holds relocation information as described below.
              If the file has a loadable segment that includes relocation,
              the section's attributes will include the SHF_ALLOC bit.  Oth‐
              erwise, the bit will be off.  By convention, "NAME" is sup‐
              plied by the section to which the relocations apply.  Thus a
              relocation section for .text normally would have the name
              .rela.text.  This section is of type SHT_RELA.
```

Each relocation entry in this section (of type `Elf64_Rela` in this particular case) should be iterated over, and the value of each entry should be addended with the corresponding value in the `.debug_info` section.

Answer (score 1):

> This tells me that the offset into the string table is 0x62, and the name is at an offset 0xd9.

Correct. These offsets are into the `.debug_str` section, which starts at offset 0x289 in the file.

```
readelf -WS elf.o | grep debug_str
  [12] .debug_str        PROGBITS        0000000000000000 000289 0000e4 01  MS  0   0  1

dd if=elf.o bs=1 skip=$((0x289+0x62)) count=75 2>/dev/null
GNU C11 7.5.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -O0 -fstack-protector-strong

dd if=elf.o bs=1 skip=$((0x289+0xd9)) count=5 2>/dev/null
elf.c
```

P.S.

> I've found sections `.dwarf_info`, `.dward_abbrev` and `.dwarf_str`.

None of above sections exit in your file.  It helps to be *precise* when asking questions.

Comment: I'll try to clarify my question (see edit).
Thanks for pointing out the wrong section names!